# Django: How to assign a template variable to a views variable?

Tags: javascript, django

I have the following code in Javascript, which takes a user's name from a drop down list and changes his/her "is_active" attribute to true:

```
function acceptFunction(){
    var select = document.getElementById("dropdown");
    var elementText= select.options[select.selectedIndex].text;
    var lbl = document.getElementById("lbl");

    {% for user in list %}
        {%  ifequal user.username strUser %}
            {{ user.is_active }}=true;
        {% endifequal %}
    {% endfor %}

    var i;
    for (i=0;i<select.length;  i++) {
        if (select.options[i].text==elementText) {
            lbl.textContent=select.options[0].text;
            select.remove(i);
        }
    }
}
```

The "select" variable is a drop down list, the "elementText" is the list's element selected the current time by the website user and the "lbl" variable is a label used to print the selected element.

In views.py I have the following:

```
def acceptUserRequest(request):
    list = User.objects.all()
    strUser=''
    return render(request, 'acceptUserRequest.html', {'list': list, 'strUser':strUser})
```

and I am having difficulty in assigning the value of elementText in strUser. Is there a way in Django to accomplish this?

Thank you.

Comment: There is but it is not particular to Django, it is a general web application workflow. You must create another view, lets say, `update_user` and use AJAX on your HTML to post the data and the view will read it and be responsible for persisting changes in the database. Or you can use a regular web form and post it to that view.

Comment: @PauloScardine thank you very much for your advice. Unfortunately, I don't have much knowledge about AJAX and it will be difficult for me to implement it that way.

Answer (score 1):

keep in mind that when a user makes a request to your app the view is processed and then a template is generated with the JS code. So if you have data in your javascript code you want to use in the view you need to make a request GET or POST, depending on the case, so the view can get this value.

For example, you could use the following GET request http://yourURL/acceptUserRequest/&elementText=True

Then in your view:

```
    elementText = request.GET.get('elementText', '')
```

If you want to stay on the same page and use ajax as we discussed in the comments do something like this. It is a very simple example. You create a view in Django which will receive the request.

```
    def accept_notification(request):
        parameter = request.GET.get('parameter', '')
        ... Do somehting with the data...
```

You may send more than one parameter as you wish.
You need a url for this view and you should attach a listener to the element in your HTML. Something like this.

```
    $("radiobutton").click(function(){
        $.get("http://www.your-url/accept_notification/&parameter=HELLO", function(data, status){
            alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
        });
    });
```

The alert is actually the callback function. In your case you can leave it blank or add a piece of code to execute after the server responds.

Comment: That is a good approach but my goal was not to redirect the user to the same webpage but to allow him/her, while he/she is present at the webpage, to be able to make this task (to change the users' attributes) more than one time.

Comment: Ok in that case you may want to do it with AJAX. If the user picks an option you trigger a request with AJAX which will be received by a new view created by you. This view will update the value in the database but the page won't refresh. I think this will help you if I understood your problem correctly. If not please correct me.

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for but unfortunately I don't know much about AJAX. Is it easy for you to show me an example of how using AJAX allows the template to communicate with the view?

Comment: I've updated my answer with a basic AJAX example. Hope it helps. Let me know otherwise.

Comment: Than was very helpful. Thank you very much!